# AIC or BIC for robust regression?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, aic, robust, bic

I want to fit a robust regression method to my data because there are some outliers that might influence the estimates too much. Now my question: Are criterions like AIC or BIC still useful for robust regression models in order to compare models with different variables (variable selection)?

Comment: I don't know robust regression, but how do you want to use the AIC or BIC? If it is for comparing the model with and without the outliers, usually you can't use those criterions for that. Models compared need to have the same set of observations.

Comment: I want to compare robust regression models with the same set of observations but with different predictor variables. Hence, the BIC would be my criterion to select variables

Comment: You are probably looking for [this](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Elvezio_Ronchetti/publication/23632931_Robust_model_selection_in_regression/links/0deec52cbb5420f128000000.pdf).

Comment: Yes I think this will help me. You know whether this robus AIC procedure is in R?

Comment: Not really; you will have to look through the robust regression packages (https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Robust.html). But this would not be hard to code up at all.